# Find out if "Force GPU-Rendering" is enabled

Tags: android, rendering, gpu, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Since Ice-Cream-Sandwich there is a developer-option called "force GPU-rendering". If enabled it refuses to Display some large Drawables. Therefore I want to find out, if this option is enabled, to inform the User that he has to switch it off, if he wants to see that drawable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find a View that you know shouldn't be accelerated, which should be any View if you add

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

to your <application> in Android Manifest, then in your code, call

```
view.isHardwareAccelerated();
```

If it returns true, the option is set as on. This has been confirmed to work on my Galaxy Nexus.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of Kai I found this [Hardware Acceleration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) topic on android-developers. Unfortunately We wanna stay compatible to 2.1 so I add my solution for anyone who has a similar problem. So inside an Activity:

```
public View contentView

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    contentView = findViewById(R.id.someId);
    //initialize Views ...
    setContentView(contentView);

    //use a handler as easiest method to post a Runnable Delayed.
    //we cannot check hardware-acceleration directly as it will return reasonable results after attached to Window.
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(HardwareAccelerationRunnable(), 500);
}

public class HardwareAccelerationRunnable implements Runnable{
     public void run(){
    //now lets check for HardwareAcceleration since it is only avaliable since ICS.
    // 14 = ICS_VERSION_CODE
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14){
        try{
            //use reflection to get that Method
            Method isHardwareAccelerated = contentView.getClass().getMethod("isHardwareAccelerated", null);
            Object o = isHardwareAccelerated.invoke(contentView, null);
            if (null != o && o instanceof Boolean && (Boolean)o){
                //ok we're shure that HardwareAcceleration is on.
                //Now Try to switch it off:
                Method setLayerType = contentView.getClass().getMethod("setLayerType", int.class, android.graphics.Paint.class);
                setLayerType.invoke(contentView, 1, null);
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
     }  
}



}
```

Comment: The minSdk version for my app is 7, my app runs smooth on nexus with  ICS as compared to the versions below 3.0,  since the min sdk is 7 so i want to switch on gpu rendering option programatically if it is already not enabled.  if the same apk used for ICS,  how can i do that?

Comment: please keep in  mind that i want to enable rendering at application level, not at the view level.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can turn it off by adding

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

If you trace the code into Window.setWindowManager(), you can see the following

```
public void setWindowManager(...) {
...
mHardwareAccelerated = hardwareAccelerated
                || SystemProperties.getBoolean(PROPERTY_HARDWARE_UI, false); 
...
}
```

Where,

hardwareAccelerated: comes from android:hardwareAccelerated

PROPERTY_HARDWARE_UI property is set by the "Force GPU rendering" option.

You can see that if user manually check the "Force GPU rendering" option, mHardwareAccelerated  variable will be assigned with a TRUE value no matter what android:hardwareAccelerated is.